# Функция не видит return другой функции или я неправильно понял про области видимости

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

number_pool = list(range(1, 91))
computer_card = random.sample(number_pool, 15)
computer_card_sorted = sorted(computer_card)
player_card = random.sample(number_pool, 15)
player_card_sorted = sorted(player_card)

def display_cards():
    print("Computer card:\n")
    print(computer_card_sorted)
    print("====================================")
    print("Player card:\n")
    print(player_card_sorted)

def lotto_choice():
    choice = random.choice(number_pool)
    number_pool.remove(choice)
    return choice

def the_game():
    while number_pool:
```

я понимаю что здесь вновь вызываю функцию выбора номера, но это я уже просто экспериментировал. мне бы хотелось просто воспользоваться возвращенным номером от функции, но я что-то написал не так

```
        print("The random lotto is: " + str(lotto_choice()))
        lotto_roll = choice
                     ^^^^^^ это значения программа не видит, вроде бы судя по документации должна
        display_cards()
        cross_number = input("Do you want to cross out a number")
        cross_number.lower()
        if cross_number == "y":
            player_card_sorted.remove(lotto_roll)
            # computer_card_sorted.remove(lotto_roll)
            print(player_card_sorted)
        if cross_number == "n":
            continue

the_game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return choice` Возвращает значение переменной `choice` а не её имя. Такой переменной не существует на уровне выше на котором ты пытаешься её использовать.

Создай её снова так:

```
choice = lotto_choice()

print("The random lotto is: " + str(choice ))

lotto_roll = choice
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, буду дальше разгребать